# How to Make custom Soft Input Panel (SIP) in Windows CE?

Tags: c#, windows-ce, soft-input-panel

How to Make custom Soft Input Panel (SIP) in Windows CE with using C#.Net?

Answer (score 2):

You can't.  A true SIP must register itself with the OS and have some specific native COM entry points ([IInputMehod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms929953.aspx)).  Since the Compact Framewortk has no support for EE Hosting, there's no way to make that happen.

Doug Boling has an example of a SIP in his book (Chapter 15), and the [sample chapter on MSDN](http://www.microsoft.com/mspress/books/sampchap/5461b.aspx) actually shows it.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a COM object that implements `IInputMethod` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms929953.aspx) and optionally `IInputMethod2` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms929954).

Comment: kinda goes without saying, but yes--it had to be native.

Comment: Just wanted to clarify, since the question specifically asked how to do it in C#.  You answer implies that a COM object can be created in C# in the CF.